# Z-index stacking context

Tags: html, css, z-index

I encountered the problem that z-index is not as simple as it sounds.

After reading basically everything I found about it, I still could not figure out a solution. So here is my problem:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL035vmw/)

```
<div id="first">
 <div id="middlelayer">
   2
 </div> 
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="toplayer">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="lowestlayer">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

I want a Div of a different parent (#middlelayer) to sit between two other Divs ( #toplayer and #lowestlayer ). I have experimentend with basically every combination of z-indices and also tried the workaround with opacity: .99, described here:

https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Nothing seemed to work so far, I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: as @Maharkus wrote - simple z-index 1 to 3 should work. Maybe issue is caused by positioning of parents?  Update jsfiddle then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.toplayer {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
}

#middlelayer {
  width: 140px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

#lowestlayer {
  width: 160px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" >      
        <div id="middlelayer">
          middle
        </div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="second2">
                <div id="lowestlayer">
                   low
                </div>       
                <div class="toplayer">
                    top                   
                </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just added `z-index:1` to `z-index:3` to each of the elements and it seems to produce the desired effect.

EDIT:

Removed JSFiddle from my answer and replaced it with a code snippet.

Comment: I think i oversimplified a little too much when creating the question. However your result is exactly what I want to achieve! Do you see a way to make it happen for this fiddle? Basically there is just one more div in #second. https://jsfiddle.net/jgbfhv1x/1/ Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be a `z-index` problem but one of positioning. Since you are using `fixed` positioning remember that the elements are being positioned relative to the viewport. To get the result you want set on to `top`, one to `bottom`, and for the last (which needs to be centered) use this little trick called [absolute centering](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/).

Here is an example you can see on JSFiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/smejLps4/

**Update:**

If the desired result is simply to "Layer" the elements you just need to apply `z-index` like so...

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/d8d75oqw/)

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. Thank you for your answer. I just put all divs to the top, so they will appear stacked when the z-index is set right. I think my question was a bit imprecise.

Comment: This fixes the issue in you latest fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/kennethcss/ucmdo8g1/

Basically, you added a class instead of an id to `toplayer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. Please check the below code.

```css
#lowestlayer {
  opacity: .99; 
}

#lowestlayer, #middlelayer, #toplayer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#lowestlayer {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#middlelayer {
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#toplayer {
  top: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
 <div id="middlelayer">
   2
 </div> 
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="toplayer">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="lowestlayer">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think i oversimplified a little too much when creating the question. However your result is exactly what I want to achieve!
Do you see a way to make it happen for this fiddle? Basically there is just one more div in #second. 
https://jsfiddle.net/jgbfhv1x/1/
Thank you very much!